# Using Python Classes and Lists to print reports from a csv

Tags: python

I have a homework assignment that I have been stuck on for several days.
Basic problem description:

Incident class has properties: ID, time, type, location, narrative and status

methods: **init**, brief, isMorning, resolve

script takes one argument, the full path of crime report csv.

First few lines of CSV:

```
ID  Time    Type    Location    Narrative
1271    11:54 AM    Drug Violation  Wolf Ridge  Report of possible drug violation. Student was referred to the university.
```

My code so far:

```
import sys

class Incident:
    def __init__(self, ID, time, type, location, narrative, status):
        self.ID = id
        self.time = time
        self.type = type
        self.location = location
        self.narrative = narrative
        self.status = status

    def  brief(self):
        print '''{0}: {1}, {2}
        {3}
        '''.format(self.ID, self.type, self.status, self.narrative)

    def isMorning(self):
        if 'AM' in self.time:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def resolve(self):
        if self.status == 'Pending':
            self.status = 'Resolved'

try:
    dataset = sys.argv[1] except IndexError:
    print 'Usage: Requires full path input file name.'
    sys.exit()

# Create an empty list to contain the Incident objects. crimeList = []

# Read the crime report. with open(dataset, 'r') as f:
    # Read the header.
    headers = f.readline().split(',')
    # Read each record and parse the attributes.
    for line in f:
        lineList = line.strip().split(',')
        reportNumber = lineList[0]
        timeReported = lineList[1]
        incidentType = lineList[2]
        location = lineList[3]
        narrative = lineList[4]
        status = lineList[5].strip()
        ### Create initialize an Incident object instance and store it in a variable
        crime = Incident(reportNumber, timeReported, incidentType, location, narrative, status)
        ### Append the new Incident object to the crimeList.
        crimeList.append(crime)
```

What i'm stuck on:
I need to access the "nth" Incident in the crimeList and run various methods. I can't seem to find a way to access the item and have it functional to run methods on.

I've tried enumerating and splicing but just can't get anything to work?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why is `crimeList[n]` not working? What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry I'm new here,cant figure out how to code in the comments.

Comment: Okay, so what's your question?

Comment: I need to be able to use that nth item as the incident for the methods established.
So I need to run 'brief' on the nth item of the list

Comment: `crimeList[n].brief()`?

Comment: Ok, that looks good so far.
`crimeList[3].brief()`
gives me:
`<built-in function id>: Breaking & Entering, Pending
        Report that someone had pried steel door from hinges. Nothing was found to be missing`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. What is your final expected output?

Comment: That was really all I needed to figure out.  I was having a serious brain fart on how to accomplish something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the nth crime from your `crimeList` like so: `x=crimeList[n]`, and then call the methods on that instance: `x.brief()`, `x.resolve()`, etc.